# JavaScript - Subtract time from a date

Tags: javascript, html

Player A is under attack, the attack is landing at 21:00
The clock right now is 15:00
Player B have troops speed that takes 01:00:00 to walk there to defend player A

I need to calculate exactly when the latest time is possible to send. This is calculated like so:

walking speed of troops (01:00:00) - 21:00 = Can send at 20:00 to reach in time.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
function SumHours() {
  var smon = document.getElementById('sMon').value ;
  var fmon = document.getElementById('fMon').value ;
  var diff = 0 ;
  if (smon && fmon) {
    smon = ConvertToSeconds(smon);
    fmon = ConvertToSeconds(fmon);
    diff = Math.abs( fmon - smon ) ;
    window.alert( 'Send troops at : ' + secondsTohhmmss(diff) );
  }

  function ConvertToSeconds(time) {
    var splitTime = time.split(":");
    return splitTime[0] * 3600 + splitTime[1] * 60;
  }

  function secondsTohhmmss(secs) {
    var hours = parseInt(secs / 3600);
    var seconds = parseInt(secs % 3600);
    var minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60) ;
    return hours + ":" + minutes + "";
  }
}

<div class="content_textarea">
    <h3>Send timer</h3>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/timecalc.js"></script>
      <p>Troops walking speed:</p>
      <input type="time" class="dataInput" id="sMon" onchange="SumHours();" />
      <p>Attack landing time:</p>
      <input type="time" class="dataInputt" id="fMon" onchange="SumHours();"/>
    <p class="content_textarea_date"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>2020-12-25 18:48</p>
</div>
```

This works perfectly as long as there is no new day overlapping.

I would need some date included, but, I'm not sure how to write the code.

[An image of the current system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nu5jH.png)

Comment: This would be much easier using the built-in JavaScript `Date` object. Can you use that?